# How to install centos 7 repos listed at https://centos.pkgs.org/

Tags: centos7

First time use centos.

How to install centos 7 repos listed at https://centos.pkgs.org/

I would like to install newer version of some applications, such as NetworkManager which by default on my machine is 1.0.6 from pub-base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [RedHat System Administrator Guide - 8.5 Configuring Yum and Yum Repositories](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html)

> The configuration information for yum and related utilities is located
>   at /etc/yum.conf. This file contains one mandatory [main] section,
>   which enables you to set yum options that have global effect, and can
>   also contain one or more [repository] sections, which allow you to set
>   repository-specific options. However, it is recommended to define
>   individual repositories in new or existing .repo files in the
>   /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory. The values you define in individual
>   [repository] sections of the /etc/yum.conf file override values set in
>   the [main] section.

Then give a look at `yum update` and other [yum Commands](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-yum-useful-commands.html).

About repositories may be useful [Available Repositories for CentOS](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories).